# Killed or Expired to use while using with someone we know

Tags: word-usage

For insurance say, sombody I know was killed in a tragic accident. So in that situation what should I use to covenvey this message to someone.
"She was killed in an accident."
Or 
"She expired in an accident."
Which one is more formal?

Comment: I would say 'she died in an accident', but do not use 'expired', it would be unusual to be used in this context - 'killed' is ok, but I think 'died' is better, at least as the result of an accident.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. What do you mean by *formal* — how you would address the deceased person's parents? How you would file a police report? How you would describe it in a newspaper article? There are numerous [euphemisms for death](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_expressions_related_to_death) and what is appropriate to a particular situation depends on many factors of culture and etiquette as opposed to vocabulary and diction. Depending on what you are looking for, this might also be a candidate for [Writers.SE] or [Interpersonal.SE], among others.

Comment: @choster, this exactly is my question. How would i communicate it with people who do know her. Also how should I communicate it with the authorities.

Comment: @arjuncc Whether or not we think something is appropriate will tend to be opinion-based, and vary by age, locale, and so on, and whether the people we are communicating with agree is also unpredictable. A web search should turn up examples of obituaries, news reports, and the like, not to mention older questions like *['Expired' or 'Passed away'?](/questions/55146)*. I do not think this question is answerable in our format unless considerably narrowed.

Answer (score -1):

Expired is passive. Someone who expired died without struggle or incident. If someone died in their sleep, you could say they expired but not if they were hit by a car.

Comment: This seems an arbitrary distinction; if anything, it is immediateness, not agency, that governs the appropriateness of *expires*. If someone is struck by a bus, gets transported to the hospital, and succumbs to injuries there, you may well say that they *expired* without raising any eyebrows.

Comment: Arjuncc, this is more simple, or vastly more complicated than your Question suggests.

British or ANZAC speakers of English think *expired* archaic though I think US American newspapers might well use it. I believe in much of India and sub-Saharan Africa, *expired* might seem ideal… and remember, that part of Africa tends to use *he is late* for *he is dead*.

*Which is more formal* could get you a very expensive law suit. *was killed* in place of TomA’s passive *Expired* could be construed as assigning blame, leaving journalists or police guilty of libel.

Stick with *She was killed*.